# Having issue in Google Analytics for the Event tracking function

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

The page I want to implement is having a form. Once the User clicks Submit Button on the form, the record can be tracked in the Google Analytics. 
I have added Google analytics code on my page. However, it doest not trigger the Event tracking function.

The code for the page is below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Keepsake Florals</title>
    <!--link to external css file-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="keepsakeflorals.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ksform.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
   <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>




      <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-87810245-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
      <script>

$('#contact-form').on('submit', function(event) {
  // Prevent the browser's default form submission action.
  event.preventDefault();

  ga('send', 'event', {
    eventCategory: 'Contact',
    eventAction: 'Information Request',
    eventLabel: 'Contact Form',
    hitCallback: function() {
      $('contact-form').trigger('submit');
    }
  });
});

      </script>



</head>
<body>

<div id="box">
<h1><a href="index.html" title="click here to return home"> KEEPSAKE FLORALS </a> </h1>
</div>

<div>
<nav id="mainnav"> 
<a href="index.html"> Home</a> |
<a href="aboutus.html"> About Us  </a> |
<a href="flowers.html"> Flowers </a> |
<a href="order.html"> Order </a> |
<a href="review.html"> Review </a> |
</nav>
</div>



<form action="thankyou.html" id="contact-form">

  <fieldset id="contactinfo">
  <legend> <span> Contact Information </span> </legend>
    <label> 
    Name
    <input type="text" name="name" id="nameinput" placeholder="First and last name"  />
    </label>
      <label>
      Email
      <input type="email" name="email" id="emailinput" placeholder="address@example.com" />
      </label>
      <label>
      Phone
      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phoneinput" placeholder="phone number" />
      </label>

     </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="orderflower">
          <legend> <span> Flowers to order </span> </legend> 
          <label for="mother" >
             <input type="radio" name="flower" id="mother" value="mother" checked="checked"  />
             Mother's day flower 
             </label>
                 <label for="father">
                         <input type="radio" name="flower" id="father" value="father" />
                        Fathers day flower
             </label>
                     <label for="otheroccasion">
                    <input type="radio" name="flower" id="occasion" value="occasion"  />
                    Other occasion flower
                            </label>

             <label for="valentinesday">
                 <input type="radio" name="flower" id="vday" value="vday" />
                  Valentine's Day
                  </label>

             <label for="others">
                <input type="radio" name="flower" id="others" value="others"  />
                  Others

                  <input type="text" name="other" id="otherinput">
                  </label>    
              </fieldset>
          <fieldset id="delivery">
          <legend> <span> How to contact you ? </span> </legend>
          <label for "question">
              <input type="radio" name="flower" id="phone"  />
                 Via my handphone number
                 </label>
                  <label for "question">
              <input type="radio" name="flower" id="email"  />
                 Via my email
                 </label>

          </fieldset>
          <fieldset id="helpneeded" >

          <legend> <span> Any help needed? </span> </legend> 
          <textarea id="helpneeded" name="helpneeded" rows="4" cols="20"> </textarea>
          </fieldset>

           <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Validate and Submit" onclick=”ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit', 'order sent', 10);”/>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you tried fixing the ” and changing it to " this can sometimes confuse the browser.

Comment: Ah, the ole smart quotes vs. straight quotes dilemma....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using improper characters in this line:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Validate and Submit" onclick=”ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit', 'order sent', 10);”/>
```

Please change ” to ", as DalmTo suggested:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Validate and Submit" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit', 'order sent', 10);"/>
```

Comment: @xhinvis you are welcome. If this solves your problem, then you might want to accept it as the correct answer, notifying future viewers that the issue has been solved.